# ARM template. Get VM address and pass as input to nested deployment

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Is there a way we can pass VM Arm template deployment IP addresses values as parameter inputs to a nested deployment.
Main deployment : VM deployments
Nested deployment: add Vms Ipaddresses as parameters

For that matter,  pass values of resources deployed in main template as input parameters for nested deployments

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible, how depends a bit on the details... do you want public or private ip - how many nic's does the vm have, how many ipConfigurations.

In general if you want to access properties of another resource in a template deployment you would use the `reference()` function. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#reference

A lot of examples can be found here: https://github.com/search?q=reference%28+repo%3AAzure%2Fazure-quickstart-templates+language%3AJSON+language%3AJSON&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=JSON&l=JSON